# Laravel/Eloquent belongsToMany returning all records

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Mostly a beginner of Eloquent here. I have got a working *many to many* relationship between two models: Venue and Category.

**Venue.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Venue extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

**Category.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function venues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Venue');
    }
}
```

I need to return a JSON object containing the venue and the related categories as a sub-property. However, using `$venue->with('categories')` returns a `Builder` object – which can't be converted to JSON – and using `$venue->with('categories')->get()` returns me a huge object containing all the venues (or so I think they are) in the DB.

What's the correct way to do this?

---

**Edit 03/27/2017:** After accepting the answer below, I'm still curious why eloquent returns that huge array of Venue objects. If somebody knows, please leave an answer anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `first()` method:

```
$venue = Venue::where('name', $name)->with('categories')->first();
```

If `$venue` is already has specific venue, use the `load()` method to lazy eager load related data:

```
$venue->load('categories');
```

Comment: Thanks, `load()` is exactly what I needed. Any chance it can be used in conjunction with `pluck()` to get a nice object with ids as keys?

Comment: @Alan you can use pluck after you `load()` the relationship. For example, `$list = $venue->categories->pluck('name', 'id')`

Comment: That assigns the plucked array to a variable. I wanted to pass that array as a sub-property, so `venue.categories` is just an array containing just key and value instead of a full object.

Comment: @Alan then instead of using load, just create this property with something like `$venue->list = $venue->categories()->pluck('name', 'id')`